# Why does turning off "Force SSL with https redirect" keep http links redirect to https?

Tags: redirects, wordpress, https, http, open-graph-protocol

<sub>I realize this question can be an XY one.</sub>

After upgrading my site from http to https, [FB OpenGraph og:image not pulling images anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8910877/3416774). The solution seems to be using http links rather than https in the og meta tags. However, the images still aren't pulled, probably because I have checked this button:

[image]

However, when I uncheck it, http links are still redirect to https ones.

Do you know how to stop this? The software are WordPress and DirectAdmin. I also used to activate the [Really Simple SSL plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/), but it is deactivated now.

Comment: "The solution seems to be using http links rather than https in the og meta tags." - but that isn't really a "solution" IMO. The cause is more likely to be FB cache or _something else_. Have you confirmed that you are not seeing a cached redirect? Have you checked `.htaccess` to make sure there is no redirect lurking in there?